# Allow searching for questions that are still unanswered after some period of time

Tags: feature-request, unanswered-questions, search, dates

I just saw the question [Add date range to "Advanced Super Ninja Search Options"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55037/add-date-range-to-advanced-super-ninja-search-options) for improved general date search options. Those would be great.

A specific useful situation would be finding all unanswered questions that are at least a day old, or a week, a month, etc.

Right now `[java] answers:0` sorted by newest will always give a bunch of recent questions first.

A new search option to show only questions that are older than at least a day or two, possibly called `unanswered`, would be nice.

```
//to search unanswered at least a week old. 
//argument could be simply one of four choices [day, week, month, year]
    `[java] unanswered:week`
```

Yes, there is the existing "unanswered" menu item, but it does not filter out recent questions.

**Edit:** I would like to see a search option like Lance Roberts has suggested

Comment: I don't understand what your question is. If you just want to support the existing proposal that you linked, you can upvote it and leave a comment under it.

Comment: I have upvoted it now. I guess I am saying that a full fledged search with a variety of date range arguments would be great, but at a minimum, maybe have a new `'tumbleweed:'` search parameter or something along those lines. I will edit my question to reflect this.

Comment: Ah, I see. Good idea... sounds familiar, though. EDIT: ah, sadly it's familiar because Jeff already all-but-declined it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14738/tumbleweed-questions-should-be-a-search-filter

Comment: Just came across that as well after doing a 'tumbleweed' search. I think that what I am after falls in between a general date search and a tumbleweed date search. As a ton of unanswered questions will never achieve tumbleweed status, possibly because they are very obscure or niche topics, there is still the need (or atleast desire) to be able to easily find these posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be very nice if you could search by date range.  Maybe make the search parameter you're suggesting more generic: **olderthan:week**, then your search would be

```
[java] olderthan:week answers:0
```

Comment: Yes, I think so. As in my most recent edit of the question and comment, a very generalized date range would be nice.

Comment: @brian_d, I think the parameter for the date should be separate from other parameter types, for maximum flexibility.

Comment: Yes, I agree with your answer. I am not sure what the 'meta' protocol is: Do I accept an answer that I like, even though it might be rejected by the people who actually decide these things?

Comment: @brian_d, you accept the answer you like the best (if there is one).  The powers that be will do what they want irregardless of your acceptance.